# Order second hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Case**

*Projects*
`id    |   Name`

*House types*
`id    |   Name    |   Project_id`

*Types*
`id    |   Name    |   House_type_id`

*Houses*
`id    |   Building_nr    |   Type_id`

All the `houses` (/apartments) have a `relationship` with `type` (XL apartment, small apartment). A type has a `relation` with house `types` (villa, detached house) and a `house type` has a `relation` with a `project`.

So three `one-to-many relationships` are being used here.

I want to `order` the houses based on the building numbers.

How I am currently fetching the data from my database:

```
$project = Project::whereSlug($slug)->with(array('brokers', 'houseTypes.types.houses' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('bnr');
    }))->first();
```

But this doesn't result in the last relationship (houses) being ordered by their `bnr`(building number).

How I load the data into my view:

```
@foreach($project->houseTypes as $houseTypes)
    @foreach($houseTypes->types as $types)
        @foreach($types->houses->sortBy('bnr') as $house)
            <tr class="table-row">
                <td>{{$house->bnr}}</td>
                <td>{{$house->type->houseType->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$house->type->rooms}}</td>
                <td>&euro;{{$house->price}}</td>
                <td>{{$house->living_surface}}m<sup>2</sup></td>
                <td>{{$house->water}}m<sup>2</sup></td>
                <td>{{$house->location}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What is the most efficient/best way to get the result I am looking for?

*Edit:

For now I have another solution to use javascript for sorting the table based on the building number (table with rows). Out of interest, is the case still solvable using correct queries?*

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
Houses::whereHas('project', function($q){
    $q->where('slug','like',$slug);
})->with('/* All your relationships */')->orderBy('bnr');
```